# The data from json server aren't loading (Angular Tutorial: Your first Angular app)

Tags: angular

I have recently tried to do the first Angular app tutorial

https://angular.io/tutorial/first-app

and when I was finished with the tutorial I noticed that the data from the json server arent loading.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HousingLocation} from "./housing-location";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HousingService {

  url = 'http://localhost:3000/locations';

  async getAllHousingLocations(): Promise<HousingLocation[]> {
    const data = await fetch(this.url);
    return  await data.json() ?? [];
  }

  async getAllHousingLocationsById(id:number): Promise<HousingLocation | undefined > {
    const data = await fetch(`${this.url}/${id}`);
    return await data.json() ?? {};
  }

  submitApplication(fistName: string, lastName: string, email: string) {
    console.log(`Homes application received: firstName: ${fistName}, lastName: ${lastName}, email: ${email}.`);
  }
  constructor() { }
}
```

I even downloaded the whole completed project and I had the same issue.

Is there a mistake on my end?

Answer (score 0):

add a try catch block to catch the error and understand what went wrong

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HousingLocation } from "./housing-location";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HousingService {

  url = 'http://localhost:3000/locations';

  async getAllHousingLocations(): Promise<HousingLocation[]> {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(this.url);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
      return [];
    }
  }

  async getHousingLocationById(id: number): Promise<HousingLocation | undefined> {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${this.url}/${id}`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
      }
      return await response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
      return undefined;
    }
  }

  submitApplication(firstName: string, lastName: string, email: string) {
    console.log(`Homes application received: firstName: ${firstName}, lastName: ${lastName}, email: ${email}.`);
  }

  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting and add an explanation of what this does.

Answer (score 0):

On my conception, first, you need to understand how Promisses work in Angular and make sure that your component is Handling the Promisse's changes.

You can [read this article](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/promises/) to understand more about this.

Than, make sure that the called route realy exist and the data is available there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HttpClient that Angular uses for network calls.

Update your Service to return an `Observable`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import { HousingLocation } from "./housing-location";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HousingService {

  url = 'http://localhost:3000/locations';
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getAllHousingLocations(): Observable<HousingLocation[]> {
    return this.http.get<HousingLocation[]>(this.url);
  }

}
```

Then subscribe to `getAllHousingLocations()` to call and start working with the response

ex: In your component

```
this.HousingService.getAllHousingLocations().subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```